# Routing Traffic from Tunnel to Eth0

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, email-server, linux-networking

Server: Centos 7
IP Provider: Cisco Switch
Configuration: IPIP Tunnel

I have a tunnel set up with an IP Provider for a Mail Server. I have many different IP ranges that I have been able to bind to my server and send emails without any problems.

We have increased the amount of emails and this have cause the tunnel to become very slow. And due to this now I need to send the emails through eth0 for better performance.

How can i route the traffic for each IP through eth0? Here is a bit about my setup:

```
ip tunnel add inttun mode ipip remote 38.XX.XX.XX local 192.XX.XX.XX
ifconfig inttun 10.101.151.2 netmask 255.255.255.252 pointopoint 10.101.151.1
ifconfig inttun mtu 1420 up
ip link set inttun up

echo "200 IPProviderTunnel" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
/sbin/ip rou add default via 10.101.151.1 dev inttun table IPProviderTunnel

ip rule
0:      from all lookup local
32758:  from 72.XX.XX.XX/29 lookup IPProviderTunnel
32759:  from 204.XX.XX.XX/29 lookup IPProviderTunnel
32760:  from 38.XX.XX.XX/29 lookup IPProviderTunnel
32762:  from 72.XX.XX.XX/29 lookup IPProviderTunnel
32763:  from 69.XX.XX.XX/29 lookup IPProviderTunnel
32764:  from 38.XX.XX.XX/29 lookup IPProviderTunnel
32765:  from 38.XX.XX.XX/29 lookup IPProviderTunnel
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default

ip route
default via 192.XX.XX.XX dev eth0
10.101.151.0/30 dev inttun proto kernel scope link src 10.101.151.2
38.XX.XX.XX/29 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 38.XX.XX.XX
38.XX.XX.XX/29 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 38.XX.XX.XX
38.XX.XX.XX/29 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 38.XX.XX.XX
69.XX.XX.XX/29 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 69.XX.XX.XX
72.XX.XX.XX/29 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 72.XX.XX.XX
72.XX.XX.XX/29 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 72.XX.XX.XX
192.XX.XX.XX/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.XX.XX.XX
204.XX.XX.XX/29 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 204.XX.XX.XX

$ netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.XX.XX.XX    0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
10.XX.XX.XX     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.252 U         0 0          0 inttun
38.XX.XX.XX     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.248 U         0 0          0 eth0
38.XX.XX.XX     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.248 U         0 0          0 eth0
38.XX.XX.XX     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.248 U         0 0          0 eth0
69.XX.XX.XX     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.248 U         0 0          0 eth0
72.XX.XX.XX     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.248 U         0 0          0 eth0
72.XX.XX.XX     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.248 U         0 0          0 eth0
192.XX.XX.XX    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
204.XX.XX.XX    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.248 U         0 0          0 eth0
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the additional routing rules to use the main routing table with default route through the `eth0` interface.

Use the `ip rule del` to do it:

```
ip rule del pref 32758
ip rule del pref 32759
...
ip rule del pref 32765
```

Also remove inserting of the rules from the network configuration scripts, otherwise these rules will appears again after network reconfiguration or reboot.

**P.S.** Don't use the deprecated networking tools like `ifconfig` and `route`.

Comment: Hi, I did exactly that but as soon as I did it the SMTP went down, even though I can ping using eth0 the mails are not going out and in the IPTables its completely open

Comment: Run the tcpdump and investigate the traffic. Check the firewall.